# Odd behavior with the List/Dictionary .Clear() method

Tags: c#

I have a code block similar to this:

```
List<Object> returnObjDataLine = new List<object>();

foreach (var tuple in dataPerTime)
{
    returnObjDataLine.Clear();
    returnObjDataLine.Add(tuple.Item1);
    foreach (var line in PlotLines)
    {
        if (tuple.Item2.Equals(line.Key))
        {
            returnObjDataLine.Add(tuple.Item3);
        }
        else
        {
            returnObjDataLine.Add(null);
        }
    }
    returnObjData.Add(returnObjDataLine);
}
```

However the `Clear()` method clears out the data already added to the `returnObjData` Dictionary, sort of. If there are 10,000 tuples, then after the loop runs the `returnObjData` will contain 10,000 instances of the very last data piece added (`Clear()` is not called after the last iteration).

If I modify the code to create a new List each iteration:

```
foreach (var tuple in dataPerTime)
{
    List<Object> returnObjDataLine = new List<object>();
    returnObjDataLine.Add(tuple.Item1);
    foreach (var line in PlotLines)
    {
        if (tuple.Item2.Equals(line.Key))
        {
            returnObjDataLine.Add(tuple.Item3);
        }
        else
        {
            returnObjDataLine.Add(null);
        }
    }
    returnObjData.Add(returnObjDataLine);
}
```

the loading loop works correctly but this seems very expensive as there can be 10s if not 100s of thousands of iterations required. Creating a new object every time seems to be inefficient.

What am I missing with `Clear()`? Is there some sort of "commit" that needs to be called first?

Comment: It's not clear what you expect to happen. In the first case, your `returnObjData` list contains the same `returnObjDataLine` reference lots of times. This is just how reference types work in .NET. What did you *expect* to happen and why? If you expected `returnObjData` to contain however many different lists, that's exactly what your second piece of code does. It's not clear how you expect to get lots of different objects without creating, well, *lots of separate objects*. If you could provide a [mcve] rather than snippets, and point out exactly what you expected, it would be easier to help.

Comment: Wow I searched for an answer to this without luck for quite a while. The answer linked above more or less answered my question. I was treating a reference like a value. Apparently the runtime "commits" the "values" of the list to the parent object (the last `Add()`) before creating the new List object with every iteration?

Comment: No, there's no "commit" - it's just a matter of understanding how reference types work in .NET.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like what you need to do is have a temporary list and a long term list...  Something like this:

```
List<Object> longTermObjects = new List<object>();

foreach (var tuple in dataPerTime)
{
    List<Object> returnObjDataLine = new List<Object>();
    returnObjDataLine.Add(tuple.Item1);
    foreach (var line in PlotLines)
    {
        if (tuple.Item2.Equals(line.Key))
        {
            returnObjDataLine.Add(tuple.Item3);
        }
        else
        {
            returnObjDataLine.Add(null);
        }
    }
    longTermObjects.Add(returnObjDataLine);
}
```

This will give you a clean returnObjDataLine each iteration without removing the referenced items in longTermObjects.

Edit To Add Reference Type Information:

By default .NET will store 1 copy of an object into memory, and then "reference" that object anywhere you use it.  Take the following example:

```
int A = 1;
int B = A;
Console.WriteLine($"A = {A}");
Console.WriteLine($"B = {B}");
A = 0;
Console.WriteLine($"A = {A}");
Console.WriteLine($"B = {B}");
```

**Result:**

```
A = 1
B = 1
A = 0
B = 0
```

Why you ask does B = 0 on the 4th line?  Because B had a REFERENCE to A, it didn't contain the actual VALUE of A, so when A changed, B changed as well.

If I wanted B to contain only the value of A then I would need a way to create a new "value" instead of a reference.  The way you do this varies for each type of object.  One way and probably not the best would be something like:

```
int B = int.Parse(A.ToString());
```

Which would convert A to a string representing the value of A and then into a new int with the Parse.  Now I have the value stored in B instead of just a reference.

If I wanted to do the same thing with a table of objects then I would have to do something like this:

```
List<MyObject> oldList = new List<MyObject>();
//Put some objects into oldList

List<MyObject> newList = oldList.Select(x => new MyObject(x.Param1, x.Param2)).ToList();
```

In this example I am basically taking each object in oldList and creating a new MyObject which is then put into newList.

Comment: He already has this in his question.  He needs someone to explain reference types more clearly to him.

Comment: While I didn't give the minus one, for those that stumble across  this and don't understand reference types, the example is wrong.  int B = A; sets B to the value of A.  Console.WriteLine($"B = {B}"); will write out 1. int is defaulted to a value type, not reference type.